# What is the different meaning of $k$-tensor and tensor of type $(p,q)$?

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and $k,p,q\in\mathbb N$.

A $k$-tensor is a $k$-multilinear functional on $V$, that is a map
\begin{align}
f:&& V^k&\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\\
&&(v_1,\dotsc,v_k)&\longmapsto f(v_1,\dotsc,v_k)
\end{align}
such that $f$ is linear with respect to each variable.

A tensor of type $(p,q)$ is a functional
\begin{align}
T:&& (V^*)^p\times V^q&\longrightarrow\mathbb R
\\&&(f_1,\dotsc,f_p),(v_{1},\dotsc,v_q)&\longmapsto T\big(f_1,\dotsc,f_p,v_1,\dotsc,v_q\big)
\end{align}
which is linear with respect to each variable.

I have a little confusion here: what is the difference in meaning between these two concepts? Do they mean the same or different thing? For which reason do people distinguish these concepts? When one say "a tensor" in mathematics, which kind of tensor is usually being referred to? And when one writes a math thesis which needs to use a tensor concept, like differential geometry or applying math in relativity theory, should the concept of tensor of type $(p,q)$ be abandoned and just focus on the $k$-tensor?

Comment: I mean, if one can abandone the concept of tensor of type $(p,q)$ for simplicity and still able to build the following concepts and results on tensor, like tensor product, tensor field .... without impedent ?

Comment: When you write a "math thesis", you define all of your terms in the document itself, either by reference to the definitions in other documents, or in definitions which you write and include in the document.

Comment: Your $k$-tensors are tensors of type $(0,k)$ in your second notation. In my experience, I think your $(p,q)$ is more commonly denoted $(q,p)$. And NO, to your final question.

Comment: So, you would never discuss vector fields or admit that they are tensor fields? Good luck doing differential geometry or GR with this attitude.

Comment: @MoisheKohan but Riemannian metric is only deal with $2$-tensor, isn't it ?

Comment: @PermQi: Riemannian metric is a 2-tensor but when doing Riemannian geometry you will be using other tensors as well (vector fields, Riemann curvature tensors), just open a RG book and start reading.